# laravel 5.8 returning false on getenv

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, phpdotenv

I have updated application to Laravel latest version 5.8 and after update the getenv() function which returns env file variable value is returning false.

However when i used  env() I am able to get the env variable value.

I have followed the official documentation and nothing is there which suggest to change from getenv() to env().

[https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/issues/349)

Here suggesting to change to env from getenv()

[PHP Dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/issues/349)

Please suggest if i need to change every reference of getenv to env or there is another way out.

Comment: "I have followed the official documentation and nothing is there which suggest to change from getenv() to env()." Because they've *always* told you to just use `env()`, I presume. You are probably going to have to replace your `getenv` calls.

Comment: @ceejayoz: getenv() is php method which should work irrespective of framework (laravel here), there was a change which was reverted in 5.8.5 hence now it works fine.

Comment: @svikramjeet Right, but if you're using Laravel, using `env()` gets you any *additional* functionality Laravel's implementation may add to the default (either now or in the future). As someone pointed out in the answers, the two even have different functionality currently; Laravel's has a second, useful parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do it is by changing from `getenv` to `env`. Also, `getenv` doesn't have a second parameter to set a default value.

Answer (score 0):

There was specific version of laravel (5.8.4) where getenv was returning false, this has been updated in 5.8.5 or above.

[Please check here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/27913)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cache `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`